# event bind mousewheel

Tags: javascript, события, прокрутка, mousewheel

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e){
  var plusScrollCard = 0;


  if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
    console.log('scrolling up !');
  }
  else{
    plusScrollCard += 100;
    $(".cards").scrollLeft(plusScrollCard);
    console.log('scrolling down !');
  }
});
```

почему в else срабатывает один раз `$(".cards").scrollLeft(plusScrollCard);`
но дело в том, что консоль лог в этом else , срабатывает столько раз, сколько прокручиваем колёсико

Comment: а что, ширина больше 1000px? Даже больше 2000px?

Comment: нет, там 100px смещение, это я забыл исправить

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что `$(".cards").scrollLeft(plusScrollCard)` срабатывает один раз? Сам себе и отвечу. Вынесите `var plusScrollCard = 0;` из функции обработчика события.

Comment: Парень, ты сделал самым счасливым меня, спасибо)))